# Radio submit in Magento header.phtml

Tags: javascript, magento, prototype

Magento v1.7

How can I submit a form in the header.phtml by listening for changes on a radio button?

This is my code, if I change the radio buttons to a select dropdown it submits fine. I can't understand

```
$groupId = null;
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

    /* Get the customer data */
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    /* Get the customer's full name */
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId()) ;

    $groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
}
$cookieGroupId = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('customer_group_id');
if ($cookieGroupId) {
    $groupId = $cookieGroupId;
}


?>

<div id="alt-nav-container">
    <ul id="alt-nav">
        <li class="icon-reorder"><span>Navigation</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="header-container">
    <header class="header">
        <h1>
            <figure>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><span><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></span>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </h1>
        <div class="player-container">
            <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
            <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
                <div class="jp-type-single">
                    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                        <ul class="jp-controls">
                            <li class="control-left"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1"><span class="play-button"></span></a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1"><span class="pause-button"></span></a></li>
                            <li class="control-center"><strong>Playing: <span class="jp-track-title"></span></strong> by <span class="jp-composer-name"></span></li>
                            <li class="control-right"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute"><span class="volume-on-button"></span></a><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute"><span class="volume-off-button"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="jp-time-holder">
                            <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                            <div class="jp-progress">
                                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-no-solution">
                        <span>Update Required</span>
                        To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!--
<div style="z-index:9999;">
<?php
//    var_export(get_class_methods(get_class($GroupId)));
?>
</div> -->
        <div class="license-type">

            <ul class="select-license-tab">
                <li><span>Select your license type <sub class="icon-chevron-down"></sub></span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="license-form">
                                <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mcustomer/group/update') ?>" method="post" id="form-group-update" name="form-group-update">
                                    <dl class="accordion">
                                    <?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
                                    <?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
                                        <div class="license-item">
                                            <dt>
                                                <?php if($groupId != null && $group['value'] == $groupId):?>
                                                    <input id="license-type-<?php print $group['value'] ?>" name="validate-one-required" type="radio" value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>" class="required-entry validate-one-required" checked="checked" />
                                                    <label for="license-type-<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['label'] ?></label>
                                                <?php else: ?>
                                                    <input id="license-type-<?php print $group['value'] ?>" name="validate-one-required" type="radio" value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>" class="required-entry validate-one-required" />
                                                    <label for="license-type-<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['label'] ?></label>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </dt>
                                            <dd>
                                                <?php print $group['customer_description'] ?>
                                            </dd>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </dl>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <div class="navigation-bar-wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//< ![CDATA[
var customForm = new VarienForm('form-group-update');

Event.observe($("validate-one-required"),'change', function(event){
    $('form-group-update').submit();
});

//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a new class to your radio to prevent conflict with forms on other page since `validate-one-required` is not unique, or use more unique class selector eg `$$('.license-form .validate-one-required').each..`

```
$$('.license-form_radios').each(function(curInput) {
    Event.observe(curInput, 'click', function() {
       $('form-group-update').submit();
    });
});
```